Inline code example for using the symbolic code "maxima" in R (via the package "rim")
Does anybody have a worked example for using the package "rim" to run maxima in R with inline code (not RMarkdown)?  We currently use maxima in a modelling class, and it would be great to allow students to explore equations symbolically in R. They could then do all numerical work in R (plotting etc.), but call maxima for the analytical pieces.
Thank you for any tips!
For example, some of this code works and some doesn't:
library(rim)
myeqn <- maxima.get("solve((1 + r*(1 - x/K))*x = x, x);")

myint <- maxima.get("integrate(1/(1-x), x);")
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1))
maxima.eval(myint, code = TRUE, envir = df)

mymat <- maxima.get("matrix([0, 1, a], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]);")
maxima.get("determinant(mymat);") # Doesn't work
maxima.get("determinant(%o12);") # Does work, using the right output line number for mymat

I would love to see more worked examples of how to go back and forth between R and maxima on the command line.

I know about Maxima, but I don't know much about rim; you might have to ask the developer -- I don't have his email at hand, but presumably it is in the package documentation. If rim has a project page at Github or something, you might consider opening a ticket there. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

I don't know if this helps, but I think I can see what the problem is. As far as I can tell, the symbol mymat (for example) is only defined on the R side of the interface; Maxima only knows about the %o12 variable.
It's possible that some of these solutions are re-inventing the wheel (the package isn't extremely thoroughly documented ...)
assign symbols on the maxima side
If you use the colon operator in your Maxima call, that will assign a persistent label in the Maxima session:
mymat <- maxima.get("mymat: matrix([0, 1, a], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]);")
maxima.get("determinant(mymat);")

You can make this slightly less painful/more magical by defining a "Maxima assignment" operator which evaluates the expression in Maxima, assigns it to a Maxima symbol, and also assigns it to an R symbol:
"%<-%" <- function(symbol, expr) {
    sstring <- deparse(substitute(symbol))
    res <- maxima.get(sprintf("%s: %s", sstring, expr))
    assign(sstring, res, parent.frame())
    return(invisible(res))
}

newmat %<-% "matrix([0, 1, a], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]);"
maxima.get("determinant(newmat)")

hacking
Alternatively (this is what I tried before I came up with the better ideas above), you can construct a table of Maxima objects that are known to R and substitute their "%o" names in a string before passing them to Maxima:
maxima_symbol_tab <- function() {
    max_objects <- list()
    for (n in ls(.GlobalEnv)) {
        if (inherits(obj <- get(n), "maxima")) {
            max_objects <- c(max_objects, list(c(name = n, matname = attr(obj, "output.label"))))
        }
    }
    as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, max_objects))
}

mtab <- maxima_symbol_tab()
maxima.sub <- function(string) {
    for (i in seq(nrow(mtab))) {
        ## cat(string, mtab$name[i], mtab$matname[i], "\n")
        string <- gsub(mtab$name[i], mtab$matname[i], string, fixed = TRUE)
    }
    return(string)
}

maxima.get(maxima.sub("determinant(mymat);"))


Cool hack, not a re-invention! You're right, the interface currently is more like a one-way only. For other interfaces like SQL-Databases, the glue R-package might be of inspiration, if not immediately helpful (never tried myself).

You can find working examples on this page, where I tried to compile a comprehensive overview of what's possible with rim. While the linked page shows examples of how Maxima works it is at the same time also a demo of what rim's knitr engine can do when used within RMarkdown files.
To understand why some of your above code doesn't work, it may be helpful to understand how rim works.
In short rim operates - regardless of whether using it interactively (what you called "inline") or it's knitr engine - in the following way:

Send string of Maxima code to Maxima
Read Maxima result as a string
Parse Result (if not suppressed) into R-code
In R, "package" all of the above into a maxima object (a R-list, with class attribute set to maxima).

All the knitr engine is doing in addition to the above is to handle rendering of the resulting maxima object into Markdown. That also means that the linked example page shows working examples equally valid for both modes of operation.
Another consequence of this is that Maxima assignment operations are not parsed as assignment operations, because an assignment is the command that is sent to Maxima and the returned value of this operation is the value being assigned - which is the part that gets parsed into R code.
One (naive) way around this could be to detect the assignment operation and make the assignment part of the parsed expression. I have the slight feeling that there is quite a number of cases where messes too much with Maxima (@Robert Dodier?)
For the other way around - referencing an R variable in Maxima code, something along the lines of the glue R-package could be possible. In that case, maxima.get() or maxima.eval(), if called with a Maxima expression that references a R-object, could look for the value of that R-object, parse it into a Maxima/ Common Lisp code representation and then send it to Maxima.
I'd suggest to move the latter part of this discussion into the Github Issue page that you opened. I'd be interested to read more about what you need.

Thank you! Will report more once we've tried a few things.
